# Android: RecentSearchProvider - Set Authority from String resource?

Tags: android, history, provider

Hi im stuck on this one.

Setting up a RecentSearchProvider as such

public class MyRecentSuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {

```
public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;
public static String AUTHORITY = "com.xxxxx.authority";

public MyRecentSuggestionProvider() {
    super();

    setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);

    }
}
```

However I would like to set the Authority from res/strings ie.

```
    setupSuggestions(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.authority), MODE);
```

Though this gets a null pointer exception.

Any suggestions as to how to get about this?
Aiden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while but i found a great way to do this.

As my app can be built against many targets, with different package names i did this.

```
String packagename = getClass().getPackage().getName();
        if (packagename.equals("com.company1")){
            AUTHORITY = "com.company1.authority";
        }else{
            AUTHORITY = "com.company2.authority";
        }
```

Hope this helps someone